# how to cmpare same types where IsGenericTypeDefinition is deff

Tags: c#, keyvaluepair

I have a issue where I want to identify if a object is of type `KeyValuePair<,>`

when I compare in if:

```
else if (item.GetType() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>))
{
    var key = item.GetType().GetProperty("Key");
    var value = item.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
    var keyObj = key.GetValue(item, null);
    var valueObj = value.GetValue(item, null);
    ...
}
```

this is false as `IsGenericTypeDefinition` is different for them.

Can someone explain me why this is happening and how to solve the this issue in correct way (I mean not comparing Names or other trivial fields.)

THX in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item.GetType() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)
```

The above will never work: it is impossible to make an object of type `KeyValuePair<,>`.

The reason is that `typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)` does not represent a type. Rather, it is a *generic type definition* - a `System.Type` object used to examine structures of other generic types, but not themselves representing a valid .NET type.

If an `item` is, say, a `KeyValuePair<string,int>`, then `item.GetGenericTypeDefintion() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)`

Here is how you can modify your code:

```
...
else if (item.IsGenericType() && item.GetGenericTypeDefintion() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: THX it work, so my mistake was that I was trying to compare a Generic type to a non generic, Right?

Comment: @SairuS You were trying to compare a generic type to a generic type *definition*. I know, this is really confusing: when I started with .NET reflection, it took me a few weeks to get used to this distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Found this piece of code, give it a try:

```
public bool IsKeyValuePair(object o) 
{
    Type type = o.GetType();

    if (type.IsGenericType)
    {
        return type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != null ? type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(KeyValuePair<,>) : false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Source:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/hu-HU/csharpgeneral/thread/9ad76a19-ed9c-4a02-be6b-95870af0e10b

Comment: Hello Rui,I dont need this, as I know that the types are equal. the issue is that I cannot compare them as one is typeof(KeyValuePair<,>).IsGenericTypeDefinition=true and item.GetType().IsGenericTypeDefinition. but type are same!